Poner valores en blanco en un formulario cuando cambio el nombre de un input
Cuando cambio el valor del nombre del crucero no se me cambia el valor de lugares ni de puertos y eso me puede dar varios problemas por eso quiero que cuando cambie el nombre del crucero se me reestablezcan los valores y se me pongan en blanco, por ejemplo si escojo el crucero Adventure y el lugar Alaska me salen los puertos de el lugar Alaska con el crucero Adventure, pero si cambio de crucero me aparecen todos los puertos en vez de aparecer los puertos de Alaska en ese crucero,este es mi código:
reservar.page.html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Reservar</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="reservaForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Nuestra Flota</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-select label="Crucero:" placeholder="Escoge un crucero" name="nombreCrucero" formControlName="nombreCrucero" [compareWith]="compareFn" (ionChange)="onCruceroChange()">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let crucero of cruceros" [value]="crucero" type="text">{{ crucero.name }}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Lugares para visitar</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-select label="Lugares para visitar:" placeholder="Que lugares quieres visitar" name="lugares" formControlName="lugares" [compareWith]="compareFn" (ionChange)="onLugarChange()">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let lugar of lugares" [value]="lugar" type="text">{{ lugar.name }}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Escoge el puerto de salida</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-select label="Puerto de Salida:" placeholder="Escoge el puerto de salida" name="puertoSalida" formControlName="puertoSalida" [compareWith]="compareFn">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let puerto of puertos" [value]="puerto" type="text">{{ puerto.name }}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>   
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Cantidad de noches</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Número de noches:" placeholder="Escoge el número de noches" name="noches" formControlName="noches" type="number"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Cantidad de huéspedes</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Número de huéspedes:" placeholder="Escoge el número de huéspedes" name="huespedes" formControlName="huespedes" type="number" (ionInput)="calcularCamarotes()"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div style="text-align: center">Cada 4 huéspedes se te añade otro camarote</div>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Camarotes</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-select label="Camarote:" placeholder="Escoge un camarote" name="nombreCamarote" formControlName="nombreCamarote" [compareWith]="compareFn">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let camarote of camarotes" [value]="camarote" type="text">{{ camarote.name }}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <div style="text-align: center">Puedes ver todos los camarotes en la sección "Camarotes" dentro de cada crucero</div>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Número de Camarotes</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Número de camarotes:" placeholder="Escoge el número de camarotes" name="numeroCamarotes" formControlName="numeroCamarotes" [value]="reservaForm.value.numeroCamarotes" readonly></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Fecha de Inicio del Crucero</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-datetime [min]="today" class="fecha" presentation="date" name="fechaInicio" formControlName="fechaInicio"></ion-datetime>
    <div class="boton">
      <ion-button type="submit" (click)="alertaReserva()" [disabled]="reservaForm.invalid">Reservar</ion-button>
    </div>
  </form>
</ion-content> 

reservar.page.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormsModule, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ReservasService } from '../reservas.service';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reservar',
  templateUrl: './reservar.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reservar.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, RouterLink, IonicModule, ReactiveFormsModule ]
})
export class ReservarPage implements OnInit {

  today: any;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getDate();  
      
  }

  getDate() { const date = new Date(); this.today = date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2); console.log(this.today); }

  cruceros=[
    
  ]

  lugares = [
    
  ]

  puertos = [
    
  ]

  camarotes = [
    
  ]

  lugaresAdventure = [
    
  ]

  puertosAdventure = [
    
  ]

  lugaresAllure = [
    
  ]

  puertosAllure = [
    
  ]

  lugaresAnthem = [
    
  ]

  puertosAnthem = [
    
  ]

  lugaresBrilliance = [
    
  ]

  puertosBrilliance = [
    
  ]

  lugaresEnchantment = [
    
  ]

  puertosEnchantment = [
    
  ]

  lugaresExplorer = [
    
  ]

  puertosExplorer = [
    
  ]

  lugaresFreedom = [
    
  ]

  puertosFreedom = [
    
  ]

  lugaresGrandeur = [
    
  ]

  puertosGrandeur = [
    
  ]

  lugaresHarmony = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Transatlántico' }
  ]

  puertosHarmony = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' }
  ]

  lugaresIcon = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' }
  ]

  puertosIcon = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresIndependence = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' },
    { id: 7, name: 'Europa' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Transatlántico' }
  ]

  puertosIndependence = [
    { id: 5, name: 'Southampton, Inglaterra' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresJewel = [
    { id: 4, name: 'Canada y Nueva Inglaterra' },
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' }
  ]

  puertosJewel = [
    { id: 7, name: 'Boston, Massachusetts' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  lugaresLiberty = [
    { id: 4, name: 'Canada y Nueva Inglaterra' },
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Las Bermudas' }
  ]

  puertosLiberty = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresMariner = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' }
  ]

  puertosMariner = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' }
  ]

  lugaresNavigator = [
    { id: 11, name: 'México' }
  ]

  puertosNavigator = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' }
  ] 

  lugaresOasis = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Transatlántico' }
  ]
  
  puertosOasis = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresOdyssey = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 7, name: 'Europa' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Transatlántico' }
  ]

  puertosOdyssey = [
    { id: 3, name: 'Roma (Civitavecchia), Italia' },
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' }
  ]

  lugaresOvation = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alaska' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Asia' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Australia y Nueva Zelanda' },
    { id: 11, name: 'México' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Pacífico Sur' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Transpacífico'}
  ]

  puertosOvation = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' },
    { id: 22, name: 'Hong Kong, China' },
    { id: 23, name: 'Pekín (Beijing), China' },
    { id: 25, name: 'Singapur, Singapur' },
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  lugaresQuantum = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alaska' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Australia y Nueva Zelanda' },
    { id: 8, name: 'Hawái' },
    { id: 11, name: 'México' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Pacífico Sur' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Transpacífico'}
  ]

  puertosQuantum = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Oahu (Honolulú), Hawái' },
    { id: 18, name: 'Seattle, Washington' },
    { id: 25, name: 'Singapur, Singapur' },
    { id: 30, name: 'Brisbane, Australia' },
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  lugaresRadiance = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alaska' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Canal de Panamá' },
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Pacífico Noroeste' }
  ]

  puertosRadiance = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' },
    { id: 17, name: 'San Diego, California' },
    { id: 19, name: 'Seward, Alaska' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresRhapsody = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' }
  ]

  puertosRhapsody = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  lugaresSerenade = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alaska' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Canal de Panamá' },
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Pacífico Noroeste' }
  ]

  puertosSerenade = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' },
    { id: 17, name: 'San Diego, California' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' },
    { id: 27, name: 'Cartagena, Colombia' },
    { id: 28, name: 'Colón, Panamá' }
  ]

  lugaresSpectrum = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Asia' }
  ]

  puertosSpectrum = [
    { id: 22, name: 'Hong Kong, China' },
    { id: 24, name: 'Shanghái (Baoshán), China' }
  ]

  lugaresStar = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' }
  ]

  puertosStar = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresSymphony = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' }
  ]

  puertosSymphony = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresUtopia = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' }
  ]

  puertosUtopia = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresVision = [
    { id: 4, name: 'Canada y Nueva Inglaterra' },
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Las Bermudas' }
  ]

  puertosVision = [
    { id: 6, name: 'Baltimore, Maryland' }
  ]

  lugaresVoyager = [
    { id: 3, name: 'Australia y Nueva Zelanda' },
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 7, name: 'Europa' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Pacífico Sur' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Transatlántico' }
  ]

  puertosVoyager = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Atenas (El Pireo), Grecia'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Roma (Civitavecchia), Italia' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Rávena (Venecia), Italia' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' },
    { id: 25, name: 'Singapur, Singapur' },
    { id: 30, name: 'Brisbane, Australia' }
  ]

  lugaresWonder = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' }
  ]

  puertosWonder = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosAlaskaAnthem = [
    { id: 18, name: 'Seattle, Washington' } 
  ]

  puertosAlaskaOvation = [
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' },
    { id: 19, name: 'Seward, Alaska' }
  ]

  puertosAlaskaQuantum = [
    { id: 18, name: 'Seattle, Washington' } 
  ]

  puertosAlaskaRadiance = [
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' },
    { id: 19, name: 'Seward, Alaska' }
  ]

  puertosAlaskaSerenade = [
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' }
  ]

  puertosAlaskaVoyager = [
    { id: 18, name: 'Seattle, Washington' } 
  ]

  puertosAsiaAnthem = [
    { id: 25, name: 'Singapur, Singapur' },
    { id: 26, name: 'Tokyo (Yokohama), Japón' }
  ]

  puertosAsiaOvation = [
    { id: 22, name: 'Hong Kong, China' },
    { id: 23, name: 'Pekín (Beijing), China' },
    { id: 25, name: 'Singapur, Singapur' },
    { id: 26, name: 'Tokyo (Yokohama), Japón' }
  ]

  puertosAsiaSpectrum = [
    { id: 22, name: 'Hong Kong, China' },
    { id: 24, name: 'Shanghái (Baoshán), China' }
  ]

  puertosAustraliayNuevaZelandaAnthem = [
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosAustraliayNuevaZelandaOvation = [
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosAustraliayNuevaZelandaQuantum = [
    { id: 25, name: 'Singapur, Singapur' },
    { id: 30, name: 'Brisbane, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosAustraliayNuevaZelandaVoyager = [
    { id: 25, name: 'Singapur, Singapur' },
    { id: 30, name: 'Brisbane, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosCanadayNuevaInglaterraBrilliance = [
    { id: 7, name: 'Boston, Massachusetts' }
  ]

  puertosCanadayNuevaInglaterraLiberty = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' }
  ]

  puertosCanadayNuevaInglaterraVision = [
    { id: 6, name: 'Baltimore, Maryland' }
  ]

  puertosCanalPanamaRadiance = [
    { id: 17, name: 'San Diego, California' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCanalPanamaSerenade = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 17, name: 'San Diego, California' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeAdventure = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeAllure = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeBrilliance = [
    { id: 13, name: 'Nueva Orleans, Luisiana' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeEnchantment = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeExplorer = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeFreedom = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeGrandeur = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeHarmony = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeIcon = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeIndependence = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeJewel = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeLiberty = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeMariner = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeOasis = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeOdyssey = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeRadiance = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeRhapsody = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeSerenade = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' },
    { id: 27, name: 'Cartagena, Colombia' },
    { id: 28, name: 'Colón, Panamá' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeStar = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeSymphony = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeUtopia = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeVision = [
    { id: 6, name: 'Baltimore, Maryland' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeVoyager = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeWonder = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosEuropaAllure = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Roma (Civitavecchia), Italia' }
  ]

  puertosEuropaBrilliance = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Atenas (El Pireo), Grecia'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' }
  ] 

  puertosEuropaExplorer = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Rávena (Venecia), Italia' }
  ]

  puertosEuropaIndependence = [
    { id: 5, name: 'Southampton, Inglaterra' }
  ]

  puertosEuropaOdyssey = [
    { id: 3, name: 'Roma (Civitavecchia), Italia' }
  ]

  puertosEuropaVoyager = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Atenas (El Pireo), Grecia'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Roma (Civitavecchia), Italia' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Rávena (Venecia), Italia' }
  ]

  puertosHawaiAnthem = [
    { id: 14, name: 'Oahu (Honolulú), Hawái' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' }
  ]

  puertosHawaiQuantum = [
    { id: 14, name: 'Oahu (Honolulú), Hawái' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasAdventure = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasAllure = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasBrilliance = [
    { id: 13, name: 'Nueva Orleans, Luisiana' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasEnchantment = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasExplorer = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasFreedom = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasGrandeur = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasHarmony = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasIcon = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasIndependence = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasJewel = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasLiberty = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasMariner = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasOasis = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasOdyssey = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasRadiance = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasRhapsody = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasSerenade = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' },
    { id: 27, name: 'Cartagena, Colombia' },
    { id: 28, name: 'Colón, Panamá' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasStar = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasSymphony = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasUtopia = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasVision = [
    { id: 6, name: 'Baltimore, Maryland' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasVoyager = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasWonder = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBermudasLiberty = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' }
  ]

  puertosBermudasVision = [
    { id: 6, name: 'Baltimore, Maryland' }
  ]

  puertosMexicoNavigator = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' }
  ]

  puertosMexicoOvation = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' }
  ]

  puertosMexicoQuantum = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' }
  ]

  puertosPacificoNoroesteRadiance = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' }
  ]

  puertosPacificoNoroesteSerenade = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' }
  ]

  puertosPacificoSurAnthem = [
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosPacificoSurOvation = [
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosPacificoSurQuantum = [
    { id: 30, name: 'Brisbane, Australia' },
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosPacificoSurVoyager = [
    { id: 30, name: 'Brisbane, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoAdventure = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoAllure = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoBrilliance = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoExplorer = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoHarmony = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' }
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoIndependence = [
    { id: 5, name: 'Southampton, Inglaterra' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoOdyssey = [
    { id: 3, name: 'Roma (Civitavecchia), Italia' },
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' }
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoVoyager = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosTranspacificoAnthem = [
    { id: 14, name: 'Oahu (Honolulú), Hawái' },
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosTranspacificoOvation = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' },
    { id: 26, name: 'Tokyo (Yokohama), Japón' }
  ]

  puertosTranspacificoQuantum = [
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosTranspacificoVoyager = [
    { id: 30, name: 'Brisbane, Australia' },
  ]

  onCruceroChange() {
    const cruceroSeleccionado = this.reservaForm.value.nombreCrucero;
    }
  }

  onLugarChange() {
    const lugarSeleccionado = this.reservaForm.value.lugares;
    const cruceroSeleccionado = this.reservaForm.value.nombreCrucero;
  }

  compareFn(o1, o2) {
    return o1 && o2 ? o1.id === o2.id : o1 === o2;
  }

  calcularCamarotes() {
    const huespedes = this.reservaForm.value.huespedes || 0;
    const numeroCamarotes = Math.ceil(Number(huespedes) / 4).toString();
    this.reservaForm.patchValue({ numeroCamarotes });
  }

  reservaForm = new FormGroup({
    fechaInicio: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
    lugares: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    puertoSalida: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
    noches: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
    huespedes: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
    nombreCamarote: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
    numeroCamarotes: new FormControl("1", [Validators.required]),
    nombreCrucero: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
  })

  async onSubmit(){
    const datos = this.reservaForm.value
    await this.reservasService.guardarReserva(
      this.reservaForm.value.fechaInicio, 
      this.reservaForm.value.lugares, 
      this.reservaForm.value.puertoSalida,
      this.reservaForm.value.noches, 
      this.reservaForm.value.huespedes, 
      this.reservaForm.value.nombreCamarote, 
      this.reservaForm.value.numeroCamarotes, 
      this.reservaForm.value.nombreCrucero)
  }

  async alertaReserva() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: '¡Crucero Reservado Con Éxito!',
      message: 'Si quieres ver o cancelar tus reservas, lo puedes hacer desde tu perfil',
      buttons: ['Action'],
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
  
  constructor(public menu: MenuController, public reservasService: ReservasService, private alertController: AlertController) { 
    this.menuActive();
    this.lugares = this.lugares;
    this.puertos = this.puertos;
  }

  menuActive(){
    this.menu.enable(true, 'menu');
  }

}

He tenido que borrar algo de código porque eran muchos caracteres pero se sigue entendiendo, solo he borrado algunos nombres de cruceros, lugares y puertos
